# bash substitution after glob not working?

Tags: bash, substring, substitution

I encounter a strange behaviour with bash string substitution.

I expected the same substitution on $r1 and $var to yield the exact same results.
both strings seem to have the same value.

But It is not the case and I can't understand what I am missing....

maybe is because of the glob? I just don't know...  I am not pure IT guys and maybe it's something that will be evident for you.

(bottom a Repl.it link)

```
mkdir -p T21805
touch T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz

r1=T21805/*R1*
echo $r1;
echo ${r1%%_S1*z}
var=T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
echo ${var%%_S1*z}

echo $r1| hexdump -C
echo $var | hexdump -C
```

output :

echo $r1

> T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz

echo ${r1%%_S1*z}

> T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz

echo ${var%%_S1*z}

> T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY

echo $r1| hexdump -C

> 00000000  54 32 31 38 30 35 2f 54  32 31 38 30 35 5f 53 49
> |T21805/T21805_SI|
>
> 00000010  2d 47 41 2d 44 38 2d 42  48 32 35 4e 37 44 53 58
> |-GA-D8-BH25N7DSX|
>
> 00000020  59 5f 53 31 5f 4c 30 30  31 5f 52 31 5f 30 30 31
> |Y_S1_L001_R1_001|
>
> 00000030  2e 66 61 73 74 71 2e 67  7a 0a
> |.fastq.gz.| 0000003a

echo $var | hexdump -C

> 00000000  54 32 31 38 30 35 2f 54  32 31 38 30 35 5f 53 49
> |T21805/T21805_SI|
>
> 00000010  2d 47 41 2d 44 38 2d 42  48 32 35 4e 37 44 53 58
> |-GA-D8-BH25N7DSX|
>
> 00000020  59 5f 53 31 5f 4c 30 30  31 5f 52 31 5f 30 30 31
> |Y_S1_L001_R1_001|
>
> 00000030  2e 66 61 73 74 71 2e 67  7a 0a
> |.fastq.gz.| 0000003a

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CrispQuirkySpecialist)

I am interested on understanding why this is not working, I can achieve my desire output using sed for example.

Comment: The glob  `*` expands to the files that it matches in the current directory.

Comment: it is set to line 7. I made it by copying/paste the path string.

Comment: @Jetchisel true but it is only one file in the dir and by echo $r1 I checked the value.

Comment: Because you did  not quote the variables that's why when the glob expands it matches the file in the directory .

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. My question is why because r1 and var are the same why the substitution is not the same.. may be is what you are saying but I can't see it.; do you mind writing a short answer?

Comment: `r1=T21805/*R1*` when you do `echo $r` unquoted ithe `*R1*`  expand and it matches the file inside the directory `T218505`, This is just a `failure` on quoting issue.

Comment: @Jetchisel I don't understand. That exactly what I want to have. I want to substitute on the path to the file inside the directory. am I understanding something wrong ? my problem is why the substitution on var and r1 are different. var is a test I made to assert that the substitution is working

Comment: `r1=T21805/*R1*` `r1` is equal to __literally__ the characters `T21805/*R1*`. The expansion of `*` to a filename does __not__ happen on assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glob expansion doesn't happen at assignment time.

```
$ mkdir -p T21805
$ touch T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
$ touch T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_002.fastq.gz
$ r1=T21805/*R1*
$ printf '%s\n' "$r1"
T21805/*R1*
$ printf '%s\n' $r1
T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_002.fastq.gz
```

It happens after the *unquoted* `r1` has been expanded. When you write `${r1%%_S1*z}`, the value of `r1` doesn't contain the string `S1`; only *after* `${r1}` expands is there an `S1` you could match against.

If you set an *array*, the assignment rules are different. The glob expands *before* the assignment, and so you can do your filtering on each *element* of the array.

```
$ r1=( T21805/*R1* )
$ printf '%2\n' "${r1[@]}"
T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_002.fastq.gz
$ printf '%s\n' "${r1[@]%%_S1*z}"
T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY
T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran it after `set -xv` to see the contents of r1.

```
$ r1=T21805/*R1*
+ r1='T21805/*R1*'

$ var=T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
+ var=T21805/T21805_SI-GA-D8-BH25N7DSXY_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
```

The `r1` of`$ {r1 %% _ S1 * z}`is`T21805 / * R1 *`.

`r1` does not include`_S1 * z`.

Comment: what is set -xv ?

Comment: I believe you could check the repl.it link I have made where i show the output of this MRE. The value of r1 and the output is clearly differents of yours.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm sorry, I'm not good at English and I'll paste the Google Translate results. I fixed it now.

Comment: @RomainL.I check the repl.it link you created.

Comment: @RomainL.I ran your main.sh (`bash -xv main.sh`). The result was the same, `+ r1 = 'T21805 / * R1 *'`.The content of r1'T21805 / * R1 * 'will be expanded when `echo` is executed.